# Is "The office where the tickets are sold" correct passive voice?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am trying to give information about "ticket office," and I want to know if my clause is correct or there another way I can give information about it.

> "A ticket office is the office where the tickets are sold"

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is perfectly grammatically correct. Or perhaps you could say "a ticket office is an office where tickets are sold", as you are talking about all ticket offices in general and not one specific one.

Comment: As @books4languages.com notes, if you are referring to ticket offices in general, then the correct sentence would be "**A** ticket office is **an** office where tickets are sold", because the sentence is then internally consistent.  If you wanted to talk about a particular office, you would then say: "**The** Parking Inspectorate is where parking fines are issued".  A final version might be: "**The** CEO's office is where **the** CEO works."

Comment: @TechnoCat On a different note, I don't understand why anyone would need to say "The *CEO's office* is an office where the CEO works" or "A *ticket office* is an office where tickets are sold" or "A *bus stop* is a stop where buses stop" or "A *coffee shop* is a shop where you can buy coffee". I am a bit confused. What am I missing?

Comment: @AIQ - These extremely simple examples - following on from the example above by books4languages.com - were intended to illustrate the correct structure of sentences such as the ones that the OP asked about - and especially to show the need for internal consistency (e.g. the "A ... an" or "The ... the") so to highlight the error in the OP's example. There is no mystery to my examples. I could instead have said "A Public Registry office is where a death certificate can be issued" or "The Home Affairs Department office is where the head of the spy agency works".

Comment: @TechnoCat I think you misunderstood me. I know what you were trying to do. I wasn't talking about your examples. I was genuinely asking why OP, who wrote  "I am trying to give information about *ticket office*", would have to say what happens in the ticket office when it seems to be very clear from "ticket office". Also why say "A *ticket office* is an *office*" - its says in "ticket office" that is an office.